# Radio grouop layout (Android)?

Tags: button, layout, radio-button

I need 4 radio buttons in a radio group, but I need them in a square pattern (2x2) instead of all horizontal or all vertical. I tried surrounding a linear layout with radiogroup, but it didn't work. What should I do to get the correct layout? Here is the xml I have:

```
<RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >  
                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="false"
                            android:text="Q2"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                            android:id="@+id/rbQ2V">
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:text="Q3"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                                android:id="@+id/rbQ3V">
                        </RadioButton>
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:text="Q1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/rbQ1V">
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:checked="false"
                                android:text="Q4"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                                android:id="@+id/rbQ4V">
                        </RadioButton>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout> 
            </RadioGroup>
```